# steps to manually parse this regular expression /([.*+?^=!:${}()|\]\\])/g

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g
```

1. `/                     /g`
2. `(                  )`
3. `[                ]`
4. left:  `.*+?^=!:${}()`

   right: `\[\]\/\\`
5. right side of the or operator:

   `\[` matches [

   `\]` matches ]

   `\/` matches /

   `\\` matches \

Is my step 4 correct? 
What does left part of step 4

```
.*+?^=!:${}()
```

match in side the square bracket?

since step 3 is a [], so it only matches only one character. Is this correct?

The regular expression is copied from here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@zerkms has a good answer. I just want to offer an alternative - by pointing you to the really useful site `regex101.com`. There you can enter your expression and you get a very nice explanation of how to interpret it; you can enter strings as well, and see what is matched.  Putting in the above expression (see http://regex101.com/r/iG3lA0 ) confirms that everything inside the outermost brackets is treated as a single character class, with escaped values for `[]/\`; the entire expression can be interpreted as

> "Match any of the characters `.*+?^=!:${}()|[]/\` anywhere in the
>   string, and return each of these characters as a separate match".

The rules about special characters inside the `[]` character class construct are a bit strange - see for example http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html. And the `/g` flag means this matches these characters anywhere in the string that's being matched (rather than just once).  Thus the answer to the last part of your question:

"While the expression inside the square brackets matches only one character at a time, the `/g` flag means the match is performed everywhere, and each matching character is returned as a separate match".

Comment: Another good site for generating regular expression explanations is http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl

Comment: @TedHopp thanks for the link; I had not come across that one, but I will add it to my list.

Answer (score 4):

There are no left or right part of step 4

```
[.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\]
```

defines a character set that consists of:

- a dot character
- an asterisk
- a plus character
- a question mark
- ...
- a forward slash (escaped)
- a back slash (escaped)

So this part of the whole expression would match a character that is enumerated within square braces `[ ... ]`

Comment: Correct. As an aside, different flavors of Regex have different rules about escaping characters inside the character class construct `[]`. See for example http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html.

Comment: @Floris: yep, I kept that in mind but finally decided to not include it since the provided expression is generic enough and would work everywhere in the similar (and expected) way

Comment: Why .*+?^=!:${}()| does not need to escape like \[\]\/\\ ?  Where can I find the official reference for escaping rule inside the []? Thank you!

Comment: In [^abc] and [^a-c], ^ doesn't mean literally, but in [.*+?^=!:${}()|], ^ just mean by its literate meaning. Where can I find detail about this rule inside []?